# How can I force a string I provide to React props is of a certain type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I would like to provide a string to a prop in a react component coming from a library. But even though the library takes in any string, I want to make sure that the string I provide is of a certain type and if not I want typescript to provide me with an type error.

I would love something like the below, but where typescript would fail.

```
import React from "react";

// Can't modify this component or props
const ComponentFromLibrary: React.FC<{ str: string }> = ({ str }) => (
  <span>{str}</span>
);

// -----

type AllowedStrings = 'Hello'|'World'
export default () => (
  <div className="App">
    {/* This should not fail */}
    <ComponentFromLibrary str={"Hello" as AllowedStrings} />
    {/* This should fail */}
    <ComponentFromLibrary str={"world" as AllowedStrings} />
  </div>
);
```

[example on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-yalow-5pg76i?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the library component in your own component that checks the type.

```
import React, {FC} from "react";

type AllowedStrings = 'Hello'|'World'

type Props = {
    str: AllowedStrings;
}
const ComponentFromLibraryWrapper:FC<Props> = ({str}) => <ComponentFromLibrary str={str} />

export default () => (
  <div className="App">
    {/* This should not fail */}
    <ComponentFromLibraryWrapper str="Hello" />
    {/* This should fail */}
    <ComponentFromLibraryWrapper str="world" />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try using TS `enum`

```
enum AllowedStrings {
    Hello = "Hello",
    World = "World"
}

{/* Both works */}
<ComponentFromLibrary str={ AllowedStrings[ "Hello" ] } />
<ComponentFromLibrary str={ AllowedStrings[ "World" ] } />

{/* Both will throw error */}
{/* You can't use anything else instead those inside the enum */}
<ComponentFromLibrary str={ AllowedStrings[ "world" ] } />
<ComponentFromLibrary str={ AllowedStrings[ "anything else" ] } />
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-shape-44o916?file=/src/App.tsx) example

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think typescript compiler is not working because of downcasting.
Type `AllowedStrings` is overlaped by type `string`.
This means downcasting is working and copiler understands `"world"` has type `AllowedStrings`.
So using wrapper component is a solution you can choose.

```
import React from "react";

type AllowedStrings = "Hello" | "World";

const ComponentFromLibrary: React.FC<{ str: string }> = ({ str }) => {
  return <span>{str}</span>;
};

// Can't modify this component or props
const WrapperCompnent: React.FC<{ str: AllowedStrings }> = ({ str }) => (
  <ComponentFromLibrary str={str} />
);

// -----

export default () => (
  <div className="App">
    {/* This should not fail */}
    <WrapperCompnent str={"Hello"} />
    {/* This should fail */}
    <WrapperCompnent str={"world"} />
  </div>
);
```